# Apatar not working properly during registration

Tags: 16.04

After downloaded the package from his official http://apatar.com/downloads.html *(for linux)*. and we found the files are following:

[image: apatar files]

```
$ cat README.txt

1. Unpack the "apatar_<number_version>.tar.gz" archive into any directory (<apatar_folder>);
2. Change system parameters for all files with ".sh" extension in <apatar_folder> directory (for example, run this command from consol: #chmod 777 application.sh);
3. To start using Apatar, run any file which has the ".sh" extension. If you would like to run Apatar as a regular application (default), you need to startup the "application.sh" file. If you would like to run Apatar as a scheduling application (scheduling), you need to startup the "scheduling.sh" file (for example, #./application.sh).

$ chmod +x application.sh
$ ./application.sh
```

[image: apatar registration]

The apatar window showed and I try to create a new user but still not working properly, why?

> I also have done try to register at http://apatar.com/your-details/register, and login with it account the apatar says ***"Your user name and password do not match"***.
>   If I close the window of ***Apatar Registration***, the entire windows is also closed.

Answer (score 0):

First: register your new account here:
http://www.apatarforge.org/datamaps/registers.html

Second: use this account to start Apatar.

Comment: I had following this step. but still doesn't work..